# Facebook like button source information

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have incorporated facebook like button in my application

Suppose you like this page
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/397/

Then, when you go to your facebook wall, you will see "fb_account_name" likes an article on developers.facebook.com.

I want my like to work in this way. My like button is not working in this manner, it does not show my website name with sentence like "fb_account_name" likes an article on

I have get my code from here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

What should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

[The open graph protocol](http://ogp.me/)

In your page `head` tags, Add:

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Site Name" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Page Title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" /> // site type (og type)
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.test/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.test/og_image.png" /> // can be .jpg, too
<meta property="og:description" content="A sentence describes your site purpose" />
```

Those above will help Facebook to understand "How to publish the user action on their timeline" when hits the "Like" button

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://example.test/myPage.html" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-send="true"></div>
```

And remember to include Facebook JS